# What could cause my D700 not to take a picture when the shutter button is pressed?

Tags: nikon, camera-settings, shutter-speed, nikon-d700

I have a Nikon D700 but when I press the button there's a click and seems like it's a super long shutter speed. But doesn't actually take the picture; the live view on the back comes on and if I press the button it sounds like it's taking the pic but with no half press focus on the button, and no pictures are actually taken.

I've tried resetting the camera and it still does this.

Comment: Did the camera ever work properly? "The live view on the back comes on" - what do you mean? It comes on when? Are you also saying that the lens doesn't focus?

Comment: Test it in manual mode with autofocus off. In most modes if it can't focus, it won't take. [Usually there's a confirmation beep when it achieves focus, but that can be disabled]

Comment: It worked fine before. I've tested in manual mode and it still does it. It only focuses when I first click the button.. then it clicks but like a super long exposure but not actually clicking again. Then when I hold the button halfway to try it snaps the pic but there's no saved pic.. I know it's a setting issue somewhere because it all started happening when I decided to follow YouTube videos on different settings and changed things.  Even after resetting everything though it's still doing it..

Comment: Try a different lens. Or try taking a shot without a lens at a slow shutter speed.
Does the mirror go up and then return? Do you get a bright frame?

Comment: Did you enable mirror lock-up? This mode is used to avoid mirror-induced vibrations, you have to depress the button twice, once to lift the mirror, and once to take the picture (after some short delay, when vibrations are damped out). Some safety time-out on the mirror lock up could make you think that the camera has taken the shot.

Comment: It seems to be working now that I took your advice.. thank you so much for the replies

Comment: Which advice worked? Would you mind writing up the advice that worked as an answer? (It's completely acceptable to ask and answer your own question) That way, the answer can be upvoted, and you can mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: I had it on live view ,, I'm still learning so I didn't know how that worked. Which made me think something was wrong.. soon as I switched it off it worked fine